# How do I beat the Toad Shuffle?

Tags: paper-mario-color-splash

No matter how closely I follow the toads, I can't beat the toad shuffle. They appear to be cheating. The only rules were that I can't touch them - so how do I know which one has the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are cheating cheaters. So cheat them better.

To beat them, you need to paint just the one toad who gets the key, the one with the crinkle in his head from the clamshell. Press <kbd>Ⓧ</kbd> to paint him. Painting more than one will cause them to shake off the paint. Start the next round & Huey will get frustrated with their cheating and call them out on it. The paint on the toad will offer the proof you need to get the `Bliss Beach Key`.